# Purpose of attaching a certificate to the HttpWebRequest

Tags: httpwebrequest, x509certificate2

What is the benefit or use of adding a client certificate to the HttpWebRequest ?

To be more specific,

Request.ClientCertificates.Add(someCertificate); // what is it's use ?

where Request is the HttpWebRequest object.

Comment: In a word, 'as a secure way of identifying yourself to the host.'

Answer (score 0):

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx
```

please  read the **remarks**  section especially on this page.

hope this page is helpful